# How to prevent `anchor build` from updating Cargo.lock automatically?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, solana

I was following [the tutorial](https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/tutorials/tutorial-0.html#defining-a-program) with [its repo](https://github.com/project-serum/anchor). After running `anchor build`, I noticed a few files have been added/updated so I could not pull the repo anymore. I tried to revert any changes by deleting the target folder and removed the `package.json`, `yarn.lock`, and `node_modules`.

Then I found whenever I undo changes in `Cargo.lock` (the one at the repo root), it would add the changes back by itself as if it refuses to revert to the repo's commit version!

Why? How can I do this?

Comment: cargo follow semver so will update patch version if I recall correctly

Comment: @Stargateur, it shouldn't be doing that unless you call `cargo update`; that's supposed to be the point of a *lock*.

Comment: Cargo needs to change the lockfile in response to changes in the Cargo.toml file. I'm guessing you changed the Cargo.toml file and committed without running any cargo commands that would update the lock file. It would help if you posted the relevant files and what changes cargo was making.

Comment: Cargo also sometimes change the lockfile after it has been upgraded, even if there have been no changes in `Cargo.toml`. But you can revert the changes and pull the repo immediately (without running `cargo` in between), and only run `cargo` after you have pulled the new repo version.